# How to string match the entire line based on the keyword using regex and empty it

Tags: java, regex

In a file there are 1000 of lines. I want to empty the line which has particular keyword.
For Example:

```
Input:
Danny akdfkldnklnflnwklfnlwen
I am sam
asndklfnklnfkldn DANNYkandfnkldnfkldnfklnskln
He is very well mannered.
klansdfnmkldnfkldnfklnsd_danny

Output Should be:
I am sam
He is very well mannered.
```

The line with keyword **Danny** should be entirely deleted to get the desired output.
Thanks for your help.

I have tried this  http://rubular.com/r/bF0RzeaFYW
But it is not case sensitive.

Comment: You're not new to stack, you should know by now to show some effort. What have you tried so far? What problems you ran into? (these questions should be answered by your question)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort is shown.

Comment: Why regex when you could use `line.contains("Danny")` ?

Comment: @MCEmperor  please take a look at the edit. I tried but the solution is not free from case

Comment: @CrazySabbath please take a look at the edit. I tried but the solution is not free from case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option would be to:

1. Read the file one line at a time.
2. Use the `.contains()` method.
3. If the condition holds, then do nothing
4. Else, write the output to another file.

If you want to do the whole thing with a regular expression, you could find this expression: `^.*?danny.*?$` and replace it with an empty string. Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/W2zSMz/2).

**Note**: You will need to provide the following flags to the engine:

- Multi line
- Case Insensitive

Answer (score 1):

From the command line: `grep -vi danny input.txt`

The `-v` flag removes all lines matching the pattern -- in this case "danny". The `-i` flag makes it case-insensitive.